# Using Event listener to measure the time on a page

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

```
 function addOnloadEvent(func) {
        var oldOnload = window.onload;
        if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
            window.onload = func;
        } else {
            window.onload = function () {
                if (oldOnload) {
                    oldOnload();
                }
                func();
            }
        }
    }

    addOnloadEvent(loadIt);

    function addOnunloadEvent(func) {
        var oldOnunload = window.onunload;
        if (typeof window.onunload != 'function') {
            window.unonload = func;
        } else {
            window.onunload = function () {
                if (oldunOnload) {
                    oldOnunload();
                }
                func();
            }
        }
    }

    addOnunloadEvent(unloadIt)

    function loadIt() {
        timeTracker._recordStartTime();
    }

    function unLoadIt() {
        timeTracker._recordEndTime();
        timeTracker._track(pageTracker, 'Category', 'Action');
```

I used the above code to implement this example for GA event tracking to measure the amount of time spend

```
<html>  
<head>  
<title>Latency Tracking Demo</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/scripts/time-tracker.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
var timeTracker = new TimeTracker();  
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker('UA-1735986-1');   
</script>  
<input type="button" value="Start Timer" onclick="timeTracker._recordStartTime();"/>  
<input type="button" value="Stop Timer" onclick="timeTracker._recordEndTime();"/>  
<input type="button" value="Track!" onclick="timeTracker._track(pageTracker, undefined, 'Manual Test');"/>  
</body>  
</html> 
    }
```

The idea is I want to measure the amount of time starting from the page loaded till the time the user navigated away. I used the GA event tracking because I want to consider it as event and group it accordingly.

Some idea how I can implement this ? Thanx

Comment: What part of the puzzle are you missing? You're asking for an implementation, but the first code sample is an implementation. So what do you want to implement?

Comment: You repeat the same algorithm in the `addOnloadEvent` and `addOnunloadEvent`. That is obviously not a good idea. You want to isolate the algorithm into a generic `addEvent` function and then pass the event type as an argument...

Comment: Yea the problem I have is that I cannot find the result on GA report and I am wondering if there is problem with the code

Answer (score 0):

When we used the `TimeTracker` code, we had something like this:

```
timeTracker._recordEndTime();
timeTracker._track(pageTracker, 'TimeTracker', timeTracker._getTimeDiff());
```

You may also now that Google Analytics now supports sampling of page load times. In the new interface, its under Content - Site Speed.

[image]